# How unlikely is it to find parasites or organisms that have parasitic characteristics in the frozen water on Mars?

Tags: planets

In the universe I'm wanting to create, I want there to be some form of disease, or infection, or parasite that someone has unknowingly caught through being exposed to specimens brought back from Mars. Is it possible for there to be life that is harmful to humans within the frozen ice caps found on the South Pole of Mars?

Comment: it's your story, you decide it. If we have been able to be infected by a xenomorph in deep space, why should a martian parasite be odd?

Comment: At this time we have no proof of life beyond Earth.  We hope it's there, but we simply don't know how it can be there (other than from a Terran perspective) and won't until we find some.  Any theory pro or con is simply speculation.  This hasn't stopped fabulous stories like *The War of the Worlds* (human bacteria kill invading Martians) or *The Andromeda Strain* (deadly alien microorganism brought to earth by one of our satellites).  Therefore, I vote that you rock on.

Comment: You can find a lot about this sort of thing via google. Btw, doing research before asking questions is strongly encouraged. Even though I won't advertise those people via a link, there are even TED talks about life on Mars. Unless someone posts a comprehensive list of literature and so on about the topic, you won't get much out of it here. The answer is simply: This is very possible because we don't know why it shouldn't be

Comment: @JBH technically the Andromeda Strain bacteria probably evolved on earth, and simply migrated up into low space.

Comment: @Gryphon, That's a good point.  The story never does establish the authenticity of its origin.  I'm biased by my teenage conclusion (teens are good at jumping to conclusions) that it was alien.  Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @JBH I'm pretty sure that the scientists in the book come to the conclusion that the bacteria are of terrestrial origin (I don't have the actual passage on hand, however).  It's never technically confirmed, but it makes the most sense.

Comment: @Braeden -- this question is in process of being closed because every answer given is the right answer. I could answer "no, it's not possible" or "yes, it is possible" or "it's your world, it's up to you!" and all of those would be right for some definition of narrative reality. As JBH says, it's your fictional world and your narrative, so answer the question yourself and rock on with it!

Comment: @Gryphon, I don't doubt it!  It's been longer than I'm willing to admit since I read it.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

On the balance of probabilities, no. Parasites are highly adapted organisms. They need to be adapted to their hosts. If there was a parasitic organism in the the frozen waters of the planet it would have to be adapted to human hosts.

Since humans are not native to the planet Mars, Martian parasites will not have had the opportunity or the evolutionary timescale necessary for their adaptation to be able to parasitize humans.

This is the case with natural parasitic organisms. However, if there were space-travelling aliens with advanced genetic engineering technology and a knowledge of human biology they might manufacture parasites that have been adapted to parasitize humans. Also, parasites capable of surviving in the frozen waters of Mars.

In conclusion, Martian parasites lurking in the frozen waters of the planet Mars are so improbable as to be considered impossible. However, with highly advanced biotechnology artificially created parasites might have been left to ensnare and parasitize unwary humans (presumably by aliens who want to turn Mars into a biological booby trap for humans).

Comment: It may, perhaps, be theoretically possible for some martian lifeform to act as an invasive species, if given a suspiciously specific commonality of preferred habitat for martian and earthian life.  Still very, very unlikely, but slightly more possible than parasites or diseases - which, as a4android mentions, are quite specialized and very unlikely to quickly and successfully adapt to alien organisms.   ... hey, I wonder if the resilience that lets whatever be the literal last species standing on mars would make it more or less likely to kudzu out on earth, maybe depending on specialization?